# Describe the subgroup of Z generated by 10 and 15.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The book ask the question: Describe the subgroup of Z generated by 10 and 15.

So I subtracted 15-10=5 which means the subgroup contains 5. What I'm not understanding is what is the subgroup Z, is that the same as Z1?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is presumably the group of the integers with adition

Comment: You are essentially finished. The group contains $5$, and therefore all multiples of $5$. It does not contain any other elements, since $10$ and $15$ are multiples of $5$. One could further observe that the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, via the mapping that takes $a$ to $5a$. (There is another isomorphism that will do the job, the mapping that takes $a$ to $-5a$.)

Comment: How would I write that notation wise? Would it be: <10,15>=<5>, that's it?